# Port forwarding to domain name

Tags: apache-http-server, port, domain, web

I'd like to mask an IP and Port with a domain, ie. so user visits domain.com and content from 127.0.0.1:4444 displays without letting the visitor view the source IP and port

What's the best way to do this?

TIA

Comment: *Mask* as in "hide"? That's not possible. Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this using DNS in a general sense. DNS (for the most part, particularly the web) does not deal with port numbers. Similarly a domain name resolves to an IP.

The solution may be to use a proxy and/or TOR network.

Comment: Thank you! I've just used apache mod_proxy and seems to be working as desired